# Running PHP without installing a webserver? Compile page into a single executable? Alternatives to PHPDesktop?

Tags: php, jquery, windows

I wrote a simple webpage using html, php (Simple HTML Dom) and jquery to parse multiple webpages to make monitoring and performing checks alot simpler and quicker. Unfortunately the server I was going to host the page on cannot access the necessary pages however it works when run using a local web server. I'm not in a position to be able to ask for access to another server.

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to share the script to my co-workers without having them install a local webserver? Preferably portable without requiring any installation. I've heard about PHPDesktop, is there other similar software or is that the best option? Is there anyway to compile it into a single executable? Is there any extremely light portable web servers that could be used?

Silly question I know, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Sonething like that https://github.com/devsense/phalanger/ Google for `Convert a PHP script into a stand-alone windows executable`

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.